# How to performantly sum all products of unordered pairs in a set of binary strings

Tags: python-3.x, performance, binary, linear-algebra, combinatorics

Given a set of binary strings `S`, where each binary string has length `L`, I want to find the sum of all products of unordered pairs of elements in these strings for each unique unordered pair. I then want to position these in a matrix such that position `i,j` is the sum of the products of the unordered pair of indices `i,j` over all binary strings.

For example:

Let `S = {101, 110, 111}`

The first binary string `s∈S = 101` has the unordered pairs `{10, 11, 01}`, whose indices are `{12, 13, 23}`. The products of each unordered pairs is `{0, 1, 0}`.

The second binary string `s∈S = 110` has the unordered pairs `{11, 10, 10}`, whose indices are `{12, 13, 23}`. The products of each unordered pairs is `{1, 0, 0}`.

The third binary string `s∈S = 111` has the unordered pairs `{11, 11, 11}`, whose indices are `{12, 13, 23}`. The products of each unordered pairs is `{1, 1, 1}`.

Summing the products, we have `{0, 1, 0} + {1, 0, 0} + {1, 1, 1} = {2, 2, 1}`.

Now I want to position these in an array based on the indicies of the unordered pairs `{12, 13, 23}`, whose order remained constant in the above. Thus:

```
0, 2, 2
2, 0, 1
2, 1, 0
```

I've written some Python code which achieves this in nested for-loops, and for small numbers of short binary strings it works well. However, I need to calculate this for `150` strings of length `10,000`.

```
import numpy as np

n_strings = 3
len_strings = 3

ordered_sum_matrix = np.zeros((len_strings,len_strings))

for s in range(0, int(n_strings)):
    binary_string = np.random.binomial(1, 0.5, len_strings)
    for i in range(0, len(binary_string)):
        for j in range(0, len(binary_string)):
            if i == j:
                continue
            ordered_sum_matrix[i,j] = ordered_sum_matrix[i,j] + (binary_string[i] * binary_string[j])
```

Are there some tricks of linear algebra, binary strings, or Python magic that could help speed things up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a numpy-maestro friend who provided the following solution:

```
import numpy as np

def sum_of_prods_of_pairs(M):
    # note: this function performs slightly better if given booleans
    # e.g. M = np.random.choice([True, False], (len_strings, n_strings))
    n_strings, len_strings = M.shape
    MT = M.T
    M_sum = np.zeros((len_strings, len_strings))

    for i in range(len_strings):
        M_sum[i, i+1:len_strings] = np.sum(np.multiply(MT[i], MT[i+1:len_strings]), axis=1)
    M_sum += M_sum.T
    return M_sum

# n_strings = 150
# len_strings = 10000

# np.random.seed(91)
# C = np.random.choice([True, False], (n_strings, len_strings))
# C = np.random.binomial(1, 0.1, (n_strings, len_strings))
C = np.array([[1,0,1], [1,1,0], [1,1,1]])

ordered_sum_matrix = sum_of_prods_of_pairs(C)

print(ordered_sum_matrix)
```

which prints

```
[[0. 2. 2.]
 [2. 0. 1.]
 [2. 1. 0.]]
```